# Conversion from TIFF Packbit to TIFF LZW

Tags: tiff, irfanview

I did a conversion with Irfanview using the Windows Command Line (advancedbatch) from TIFF Packbit to TIFF LZW. 
When I open the file in ESA SNAP it loads extremely slow. I have the same Picture which was converted in the same way with Irfanview last year which works just fine. In the Metadata the only difference is the RowsPerStrip. Do you have an idea why it loads extremely (means it takes >5 mins to load..) slow?

The only difference in the Metadata:

RowsPerStrip : 1024 (this Tiff LZW loads extremely slow)

RowsPerStrip : 1 (this TIFF LZW works fine)

Comment: Please edit you question to include the Metadata as content, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: ..ok, it's edited, see above

Comment: Can you share those files?

Comment: @cgohlke How would you like me to share the examples? Per Mail? or is there another way to share the files on StackOverflow?

Comment: Try Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox, etc